# An efficient private messaging solution for millions?

Tags: mysql, cassandra, messaging, pusher

I have an app, both web and mobile, that needs an efficient private messaging system for what could eventually be millions of users. All that come to mind are the PM systems of the message boards everyone's used at one point or another & the Jabber/XMPP Instant Messaging protocol.

Ideally it'd be something similar to Facebook's chat system in terms of the end-user layout (where all messages from a particular friend are put on the same page), but that's pretty much just a matter of adapting the UI.

The most intimidating thing is the idea that this PM system would need to work for potentially millions of users. With this many users, what should I try to implement?

Currently checking out Pusher, but I'm worried about the cost.

Comment: Such a system already exists. It's called e-mail. ;-) Anyway, don't build for millions of users just yet. Aim for thousands and you'll be safe for now. If you have millions of users, you will need additional servers that will probably need to be clustered. You will need extra manpower to develop that system and you'll run into limits you couldn't possibly think of now. Don't over complicate and make realistic targets.

Comment: Once upon a time, it was called irc

Comment: @GolezTrol I know, right?! Part of me thinks it'd be best to use a private email server that's blocked off from the outside world since email has every feature you could ever want besides some real-time notification stuff. But yeah I just wanted to see if anyone knew of a library/plugin that made it easy to set up such a common functionality the right way.

Comment: Are you doing real-time messaging?  You wouldn't use an email-backed system for that.  Plus the overhead (header-to-body ratio) is too high.  Seems like a narrow table (from_id, to_id, datestamp, body) is all you need.

Comment: @AlainCollins Smart man, thanks for the overhead warning! Real-time would be nice, sure, but really I just care that new messages permeate the system within 15 seconds, that the device can be aware of new messages automatically (the equivalent of Push notifications), and ideally the system is aware of when each message is read vs. unread. That really just means a new column in that table so it looks like "from_id, to_id, datestamp, body, read_status"... A database like that would be able to efficiently scale to millions of users?

Comment: There are so many aspects to scalability, so I couldn't possibly guarantee you success!  Good hardware, tons of RAM, fast disks, a good application cache, good innodb tuning - all of these things will play a huge role.  Also be sure to have a retention policy for both 'read' and 'stale' messages.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with PlayOrm and Cassandra and playframework as a start and just have a very simple table.  If you use the playframework, it makes it very easy to do websockets for long polling and playframework can do 1000's of sockets on just a few threads.  It would seem just as easy to design for millions of users as it would be to design for 1000's of users so while I agree with design for 1000's as success helps you hire more and change the solution into a scalable solution, it is not hard to design a scalable solution out of the gate these days either.

The only other thing I think you really need to solve is when one request comes into one play server, you need to send out the message to all the other servers as you don't know which one has the websocket listening for the event....there are some libraries out there that can help solve that.

so

1. store the item in the users queue of messages
2. send message to all other webservers there is a message for users X,Y,Z(group lots of incoming in one message to reduce load)
3. servers that have websockets for user X, Y, Z can easily respond to their respective user with the message immediately that just came in.

It is a fun problem to think through.

Dean

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I'm certainly going to refer to it later on when development really gets rolling!